# Why would changing a light bulb cause the oven heat and control to fail?

Tags: repair, oven

I recently replaced the bulb on my oven. However I did put back the insulating looking ring. I pushed the oven light button while baking nachos. I heard a pop and the heat went out as did the light and digital display that shows temp, time... The burners still work though. New wires inside needed? New fuse? Can someone please help!

Comment: Are these electric or gas burners?

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned an insulating ring and every thing was fine until you turned on the light there is a short in the wiring (the pop) was something going to ground. Hopefully there is a fuse but some damage to the wiring or control board is likely if not fused inside the controller. With the power off look for a fuse and or blown traces on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there may be a fuse in the oven/range itself, but it is strange that a light bulb would have blown it.

It could also be on a GFCI breaker which tripped (which is separate from the normal power line breaker).

But since everything went off at the same time, it sounds like a fuse. It could also be a computer controller, but that tends to be really rare and most ovens/ranges I know about don't have significant computer control.

Comment: I doubt it- if the breaker on the circuit tripped, the stovetop couldn't work.   And I dunno about where you live, but most models the last 20 yrs (other than rock-bottom ones) in the USA have touchpanels, programmable start/stop stuff, etc.  There's for sure a micro in there.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed he said the top worked after posting... A lot of lower-end ones (like what might come standard with houses) that I've seen (AZ, USA, tract housing, sample size including a '92 house, a '94 house, a '99 house, and an '06 apartment complex) had digital monitoring (temperature and a timer) but the controls seemed more primitive, with micro-controllers I wouldn't expect to fail - ever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain it was my oven light that caused a loud electric sound and blew my breaker, I turned the oven to 400 and went and sat down while it pre heated and then around 5 minutes laterI heard a loud noise and it sounded like you would imagine electric to sound like.i ran to kitchen and seen white smoke coming from under top where the burners are so I removed back panels and observer smoke damage around the ceramic piece that the bulb goes in and when I removed it , the bulb fell out, it had separated from it's metal base causing a couple tiny wires to cross. Funny thing is the filament in the bulb was still good lol

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/156053)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).